# Why does Database.getQueryLocatorWithBinds fail to find the binds in the bind map?

Tags: apex, soql

We are trying to use the new `Database.getQueryLocatorWithBinds` feature but for some reason, we are getting an error that the bind variable cannot be found.

Here's an updated example:

```
public Database.QueryLocator queryLocatorByExample(Date activationDate) {
    // Status is Picklist field, activateDate is a Date data type on object
    final Map<string, Object> bindMap = new Map<String. Object> {
        'status' => Constants.ACTIVE, // 'Active'
        'activationDate' => activationDate
    }
    final String soql = newQueryFactory()
        .setCondition(
                Example__c.Activation_Date__c + ' <> null and ' +
                Example__c.Activation_Date__c + ' <= :activationDate and ' + 
                Example__c.Status__c + ' = :status')
        .toSOQL();
    return Database.getQueryLocatorWithBinds(soql, bindMap, AccessLevel.USER_MODE);
}

// Somewhere in another class, call the Selector:
Date activationDate = Date.newInstance(2020, 1, 1);
// Instantiate selector, then...
Database.QueryLocator locator = selector.queryLocatorByExample(activationDate);
// This throws:
//// System.QueryException: Variable does not exist: status

// However, if we first declare status in the calling code, everything works fine:
Date activationDate = Date.newInstance(2020, 1, 1);
String status = 'Active'; // Note, one does not have to pass this magical variable.
Database.QueryLocator locator = selector.queryLocatorByExample(activationDate);
// All works fine!
//// :)
```

I've tried both System and User mode to the same affect. I have read/write access to the status field. When I create the `status` variable in the calling code, it stops failing on `status` and works fine. Status is a picklist, but I would not expect that to make any difference.

The API version of our code is 59, so the feature should work.

As @BritshBoyinDC suggested, I checked to make sure my data types are correct (for example, make sure I'm not sending in a date time value into activation date), but these are all fine. And again, so long as I also declare `status` as a variable in the calling code, it works fine.

This particular error is one of many I am getting trying to use this feature. In multiple queries I tried to use this feature and they all fail due to not finding a variable. It has never worked for me.

Is this feature fully working for someone else? Am I doing something wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: Just a quick sanity check: Since you're using user mode, do you have FLS set up appropriately for `Status__c`?

Answer (score 1):

I asked someone at SFDC about that error, and they said it can be misleading. It probably means one of the fields has a type mismatch e.g. with this example, I get an error with activationDate, even though the error is actually a type mismatch with the with the NumberOfEmployees ( I am passing in a string when it wants an Integer)

```
Map<String, Object> bindMap = new Map<String, Object> {
        'activationDate' => Datetime.now(),
        'NumberOfEmployees' => 'Other'
};

Database.QueryLocator dq = DataBindPOC.getWithBinding(bindMap);
```

So I think you'd need to see the variables you are passing in for  activationDate and status. Because this example does work for me:

```
public with sharing class DataBindPOC {

   public static Database.QueryLocator getWithBinding(Map<String, Object> bindMap ) {
        return Database.getQueryLocatorWithBinds(
                'select Id from Account where CreatedDate < :activationDate ' +
                        ' and Type  = :type', bindMap, AccessLevel.USER_MODE);
    }
}

 Map<String, Object> bindMap = new Map<String, Object> {
        'activationDate' => Datetime.now(),
        'type' => 'Other'
};

Database.QueryLocator dq = DataBindPOC.getWithBinding(bindMap);
System.debug(dq.getQuery());
```

This also works for me:

```
public with sharing class DataBindPOC {
    public Static String sStatus = 'Customer';

    public Database.QueryLocator getWithBinding2(DateTime activationDate) {

        final Map<string, Object> bindMap = new Map<String, Object> {
            'type' => DataBindPOC.sStatus,
            'activationDate' => activationDate
        };

        return Database.getQueryLocatorWithBinds(
                'select Id from Account where CreatedDate <> null AND CreatedDate < :activationDate ' +
                        ' and Type  = :type', bindMap, AccessLevel.USER_MODE);
    }
}

DateTime activationDate = DateTime.newInstance(2024, 2, 1);
DataBindPOC dpc = new DataBindPOC();
Database.QueryLocator dq = dpc.getWithBinding2(activationDate);
```

Comment: @BritshBoyinDC I wish my issue was data type. Both of my data types are corrects and the query action works fine if I declare a variable of the same name `status` in the calling code.

Comment: @swishersweet can you share your exact code that you're trying? your initial post doesn't have a value for activationDate/status, so I can't reproduce.

Comment: @ChristianCarter a more robust code example has been added to the question. Thank you.

Comment: @SwisherSweet please include the definition of Constants.ACTIVE

Comment: I just noticed that your `bingMap` is not defined in the method `getWithBinding` but rather with the calling code. Does the map have to be defined in the calling method? If so, seems that negates the benefit of having a bind map, IMHO.

Comment: @ChristianCarter string value, 'Active'.

Comment: See my example in the answer - doesn't need to be defined in the method - you can just pass it in via the method parameters

Comment: Any chance it is the soql builder doing something weird?